# Letter frequency array, converting int to char

Tags: java

My code below prints out a letter frequency table (number of letter occurances in a string) that is inputted from a scanner class. I Have everything working correctly except the last bit. When executed, the table displays letters a-z and the number of occurrences except for the last method LargestLength() method. Since my array 'score' uses int[26], instead of using a-z it uses ints 0-25. (0=A, 1=B, etc.) As of now my LargestLength method only displays the number (instead of the letter) which comes up the most but does not count the number of occurrences.

For example, If my string were to be "Hello", l shows up most frequently so i would like it to display, "Most Frequent: l 2" but with my code it displays "Most Frequent: 11" (11 = L). How would I go about fixing this?

Profile Class.

```
public class LetterProfile {
  int score[] = new int [26];

   public void countChars (String s) {
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    char a = 'a';
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      int next = (int)s.charAt(i) - (int) a;
      if ( next< 26 && next >= 0)
        score[next]++;

    }
 }

    public int largestLength() { 
      int largest = 0;
      int largestindex = 0;
      for(int a = 0; a<26; a++) {
        if(score[a] > largest) {
        largest = score[a];
        largestindex = a ;


      }
      }
      return (char) largestindex;
    }

    public void printResults() {
       largestLength();

       for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
    System.out.println( (char)(i+97) + ": " + score[i]);
       }
  System.out.println(("Most Frequent") + (": ") + largestLength());
    }
}
```

A bit of a confusing explanation but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If my string were to be "Hello", l shows up most frequently so i would like it to display, "Most Frequent: l 2" but with my code it displays "Most Frequent: 11" (11 = L). How would I go about fixing this?

Simple: `String.valueOf((char)(number + 'A'));`

Comment: Oh, if it's not too much trouble I want to be able to display the number of occurrences for that letter. I cant figure out what to add to my largestLength() method for it to do that?

Comment: @aiuna: Let's see your best effort to solve this. You shouldn't really need our help for this.

Comment: Having no luck, I know its simple too. Any hints?

Comment: @aiuna: Please show your latest best attempt as an addendum to your original question.

Comment: @aiuna: sweet! and congrats!